What is a simple way to copy a partition from one list to another list?
I have two lists of the same length at their bottom level and one contains sublists of various lengths:
A={{1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9}};
B={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i};

Is there some straightforward way, e.g. using Partition, to copy the partition from A to B, to get the result
Bp={{a,b,c},{d,e,f,g},{h,i}}

?

Here's one way:
TakeList[B, Length /@ A]


Update:
ClearAll[CLS]
CLS[a_, b_] /; Length[Flatten @ a] == Length[Flatten @ b] := 
 Internal`CopyListStructure[a, Flatten @ b]

Examples:
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9}};
B = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};

CLS[A, B]


{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f, g}, {h, i}}


CLS[B, A]


{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}


A2 = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, {{6, {{7}}}}}, {8, 9}};
B2 = {a, b, c, {{{d}}}, e, {f}, g, h, i};

CLS[A2, B2]


{{a, b, c}, {d, e, {{f, {{g}}}}}, {h, i}}


CLS[B2, A2]


{1, 2, 3, {{{4}}}, 5, {6}, 7, 8, 9}


Original answer:
    Internal`CopyListStructure[A, B]
>     {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f, g}, {h, i}}


Explore the documentation a bit and discover an example showing FoldPairList doing exactly what you asked for.
A={{1,2,3},{4,5,6,7},{8,9}};
B={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i};
FoldPairList[TakeDrop,B,Map[Length,A]]

which returns
{{a,b,c},{d,e,f,g},{h,i}}

If you are new and you are wondering how I found that and how you might be able to find something like this on your own, I thought that I wanted to Take items from that list, I looked at the documentation for that, thinking I might find some way to tell Take to do that, at the bottom of the help I saw TakeDrop and looked at the help for that, that seemed closer to what I wanted, but still didn't seem to be quite what I was looking for, but at the bottom of that I saw FoldPairList and that included an example doing exactly what you asked for, I just needed to use Map and Length to find the lengths of each sublist.

Yet another way
A /. i_Integer :> B[[i]]


A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9}};
B = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};
A2 = {{1, 20, 3}, {x, {52, {6}}, 7}, {1, 80}};
A3 = {{1, 20, 3}, {x, {52, {6}, {}}, 7}, {1, 80}};

Function[Null, 
  Evaluate[
   ReplacePart[#, 
      Thread[Position[#, Except[_List], \[Infinity], Heads -> False] ->
         Array[Slot, Length@Flatten@#]]] &[A3]]][Sequence @@ B]

(* {{a, b, c}, {d, {e, {f}, {}}, g}, {h, i}} *) 


Function[Null, 
 Evaluate[
  ReplacePart[#, 
     Thread[Position[#, Except[_List], \[Infinity], Heads -> False] ->
        Array[Slot, Length@Flatten@#]]] &[A3]]]

(* Function[Null, {{#1, #2, #3}, {#4, {#5, {#6}, {}}, #7}, {#8, #9}}] *)

copyLS
copyLS[a_List, b_List] := 
 Function[Null, 
   Evaluate[
    ReplacePart[#, 
       Thread[Position[#, Except[_List], \[Infinity], 
          Heads -> False] -> Array[Slot, Length@Flatten@#]]] &[a]]][Sequence@@b]

copyLS[A, B]
copyLS[A2, B]
copyLS[A3, B]
copyLS[A2, Join[B, {20}]]

(* 
  {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f, g}, {h, i}}
  {{a, b, c}, {d, {e, {f}}, g}, {h, i}}
  {{a, b, c}, {d, {e, {f}, {}}, g}, {h, i}}
  {{a, b, c}, {d, {e, {f}}, g}, {h, i}}
*)

copyLS[A, B] == Internal`CopyListStructure[A, B]
copyLS[A2, B] == Internal`CopyListStructure[A2, B]
copyLS[A3, B] == Internal`CopyListStructure[A3, B]

(* True True True *) 

